# WordPress Taxonomy - OrderBy issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following query in WordPress. I'm trying to get all my posts from a specific taxonomy and order BY **title**. It gets the posts great but orders by date(??).

Here's the query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'faces',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' =>  array (
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'faces-page',
            'terms' => array(25, 29, 30),
            'field' => 'id',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
 ));
```

Can anyone advise why when I run `var_dump($the_query->request);` immediately after this code, my output is the following (see ORDER BY):

```
    SELECT wcolp_posts.* 
FROM   wcolp_posts 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND ( wcolp_posts.id NOT IN (SELECT object_id 
                                    FROM   wcolp_term_relationships 
                                    WHERE  term_taxonomy_id IN ( 25, 29, 30 )) ) 
       AND wcolp_posts.post_type = 'faces' 
       AND ( wcolp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
              OR wcolp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' 
              OR wcolp_posts.post_status = 'private' ) 
GROUP  BY wcolp_posts.id 
ORDER  BY wcolp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Surely it should be order by title, not date? Help please :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'faces',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' =>  array (
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'faces-page',
            'terms' => array(25, 29, 30),
            'field' => 'id',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
 ));
```